# G Suite vs Firebase SSO for internal applications

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, single-sign-on, google-workspace

Our organization uses G Suite and we want to implement SSO with different roles in an application we built but I'm a bit confused about the alternatives. We used Firebase for another application with a backend check that the email domain belonged to our organization, and it seems that roles can somewhat be implemented in Firebase via "claims". It doesn't really feel like Firebase is built for our use case though (limiting login to a single email account domain), but rather applications where anyone should be able to login.

Does G Suite (SAML?) offer something simple that can use G Suite groups and covers our use case or are we better off hacking this into Firebase? The main goals are to avoid needing our own admin user database, having administration in a single place and be able to centrally deactivate users who quit the company so they aren't left with a bunch of admin accounts.